# Javascript print function uses the printer on browser instead

Tags: javascript

For some reason using

```
    var sample = "test";
    print(sample);
```

the print function doesn't print the string on the web browser , however it literally uses the print function on my chrome browser .
any idea why ? 
Im actually learning javascript from http://eloquentjavascript.net/   and it uses the print function too.

Comment: if you want to print something on the page use `document.write()` if you want to print something for debugging purpose use `console.log()`

Comment: As the book says, "`print` is not a standard JavaScript function, browsers do not provide it for you, but it is made available by this book, so you can use it on these pages".

Comment: @TilwinJoy, that is an answer in itself. Place that as an answer along with some extra explanation.

Comment: @JilwinJoy Using document.write [is often discouraged for various reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/802943/975097), so it might be better to use another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window.print()` method opens the print dialog to print the current document, Not part of any standard. ( [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.print))

If you want to print something in your page, use `document.write()` function. The text you write is parsed into the document's structure model

read more at [MDN - document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)

if you want to print something for simple debugging purpose, `use console.log()`, which prints the output in browsers console. read more at [MDN - console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log)